# Can I deploy an API built with R and Plumber Package on MS Azure?

Tags: r, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, plumber

I built an API using R and Plumber and was wondering if I could deploy it on Azure. It is a simple REST API and it launches Swagger to run. I tried deploying on Azure and it does not seem like R is supported. I wanted to get you guys thoughts and see if I am overlooking any deploying options Azure may have to offer for it.

It is a simple RESTful API that takes data from a table in a MS SQL Server database and shares that data when the API is called.

Hoping to hear you guys recommendations on this.

Comment: Is this helpful?
https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2020/12/azure-functions-with-r.html

Comment: Thank you! It might actually help. Let me try it and circle back.

Answer (score 1):

The process involves:

1. use a couple of Azure CLI commands to set up a project on your local machine and create Azure resources.
2. write a “handler” script in R to provide a Web service, and push a Docker container with the Azure Functions runtime, R engine, and packages needed to implement your Function.
3. Then, when you want to update your Function all you need to do is push a new version of the container image with the updated R code

Reference :

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?pivots=programming-language-other&tabs=bash%2Cportal&WT.mc_id=aiml-11825-davidsmi
2. https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2020/12/azure-functions-with-r.html

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the response. We ended up setting up a Linux Redhat Centos8 server to deploy the API on, and I have the same question. So I will be creating another post for it, hoping to get an answer on how to deploy/run it on the server.